# StackExchange.Redis Transaction

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stackexchange.redis

How can I run two asynchronous methods in one transaction?

For example:

```
  var batchIds = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
  var trans = redis.CreateTransaction();

  var task = trans.ListRangeAsync(AllItems, 0L, batchSize - 1).ContinueWith(t =>
   {
    t?.Result.ToList().ForEach(x => batchIds.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StockItemDto>(x).Id));
     }).ContinueWith(t=>{ trans.ListTrimAsync(AllItems, batchSize, -1); });  // This not work

  // This work but I'm not sure if taskRemove run exaclly after task
  var taskRemove = trans.ListTrimAsync(AllItems, batchSize, -1);                    
  trans.Execute(CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
  Task.WaitAll(task, taskRemove);
```

Maybe someone knows how to get a range from list and later remove this range in transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this.

The solution is creating a regular `IDatabase` for read operations and an `ITransaction` for write operations.

*Why...?* Because *StackExchange.Redis* transactions are an abstraction of Redis' `MULTI`/`EXEC` commands. That is, a transaction is a queue of commands sent in batch to Redis and their execution is atomic. The whole *send in batch* part is done once you call `ITransaction.Execute`.

That's the reason to not being able to perform read operations within a Redis transaction. Commands are queued and executed in batch, thus, you can *continue with whatever* once the bacthing has ended, and this won't be as part of the wrapped transaction...

### OP said in some comment...

> Maybe you can something suggest for me? Because I need to get items
>   from list and after delete this items. And these operations must be
>   thread-safe.

Thread-safety has nothing to do with Redis transactions at all. It's you who's responsible of implementing some locking approach as part of your application layer. Well, you might be able to implement that *lock* using Redis as *inter-process* or *multi-thread* lock flag storage. [Read about this on this article from official Redis site.](http://redis.io/topics/distlock)

In fact, check this other Q&A: [StackExchange.Redis - LockTake / LockRelease Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127172/stackexchange-redis-locktake-lockrelease-usage)

Comment: Maybe you can something suggest for me? Because I need to get items from list and after delete this items. And these operations must be thread-safe.

Comment: @PavloDenys I've already provided you a suggestion. Read the second paragraph of my answer! :) And this has nothing to do with thread-safety, and if you want to coordinate your write operations, your approach or "desired approach" won't work. You'll need to implement some locking approach to block other threads from accessing/modifying certain keys in your application layer...

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement this.

Comment: @PavloDenys Check again the answer. I've provided you another Q&A where I believe you'll get an easy solution for your problem! ;)