# AppFabric Cache to Redis - equivalent of the GetAndLock method?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, appfabric-cache

I'm currently moving from Microsoft AppFabric Cache to Redis on Windows.
In the past, I was using the GetAndLock method of AppFabric.
Is there a method in Redis to do a GetAndLock ? (I'm using the StackExchange.Redis.StrongName nugget lib).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackExchange.Redis has some locking methods, if you're trying to protect a critical code section from being run more than once at a time.

```
if (connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase().LockTake(key, token, duration))
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        connectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase().LockRelease(key, token);
    }
}
```

There are also `LockExtend` and `LockQuery` methods.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25138164/2497886 for some more detailed information.

It's also worth having a look at the redis documentation on distributed locks - http://redis.io/topics/distlock.

The [RedLock.net](https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net) library implements the distlock algorithm, and supports things like blocking/retrying to obtain a lock and automatic lock extension. (disclaimer: I am the author of the library)